# How to properly handle entity relations

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data

Table [machines] contains physical column name [machine_id] referred to by multiple physical column names: [machine_id], [machineId].

The cause of it appears to be because of my entity relations I have:

```
@Entity(name = "lineups")
public class Lineup {
  // ...
  private long machineId;

  @ManyToOne(..)
  private Machine machine;
  // ...
}

public class LineupDto {
  // ...
  private long machineId;
  // ...
}
```

However if I comment out property `machineId` everything starts working as expected. However this this means that my Lineup DTO has to contain a Machine object instead of just an `machineId`.

I was looking for a way where I could have a controller which accepts either `Lineup` json object with either `machineId` or `Machine object` but could not make it work.

However now if I have to comment out `machineId` than I cannot transition data easily between Dto & Entity.

Is there a way I can have both machineId & machine properties ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest move the annotations to the methods instead of the fields and mark machineId as `@Transient` which tells hibernate to ignore that particular property and not try to persist it. Then just make the getMachineId method return the id of the Machine object.

```
@Entity(name = "lineups") 
public class Lineup {
  // ...
  private long machineId;
  private Machine machine;
  // ...
  @Transient
  public long getMachineId() {
      return machine.getId();
  }

  @ManyToOne(..)
  public Machine getMachine() {
      return machine;
  }
 }
```